# .NET Core throws WindowsCryptographicException: Access is denied on X509Store.Add

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, certificate, x509certificate2

I write a method to install a certificate:

```csharp
public void Install(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation)
{
    using var store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(cert);
}
```

and invoke it by passing StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser

```csharp
certificateManager.Install(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
```

will result in:

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Access is denied.
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.StorePal.Add(ICertificatePal certificate)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store.Add(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at Pixeval.Persisting.WebApi.CertificateManager.Install(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation) in C:\NotSystem\Coding\projects\visualstudio\csharp\Pixeval\Persisting\WebApi\CertificateManager.cs:line 99
   at Pixeval.App.InstallFakeCaCertificate() in C:\NotSystem\Coding\projects\visualstudio\csharp\Pixeval\App.xaml.cs:line 129
   at Pixeval.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in C:\NotSystem\Coding\projects\visualstudio\csharp\Pixeval\App.xaml.cs:line 68
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_0(Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Pixeval.App.Main()
```

after googling I found mostly relevant questions are asking for StoreLocation.LocalMachine, I didn't found any solution for install a certificate at StoreLocation.CurrentUser

Note: I cannot reproduce this issue because it's posted by one of the users of my application

Comment: are you running the app as administrator?

Comment: I tested on my own computer without running on administrator and it works fine, I thought to install the cert on Current User won't need Administrator permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues, one is associated with configuration and another with the code itself.

## Issue 1:

The exception is raised because `CurrentUser.Root` store is readonly. It seems that your systems administrator configured GPO to restrict users from writing to this store:

[image]

## Issue 2:

Even if you fix this, the code may fail in a different way: it may hang/freeze. This is because when you install certificates to `CurrentUser.Root`, a popup is invoked (you can't avoid this pop-up) to confirm the operation:

[image]

I haven't tested, but if the code is invoked in a background thread, then the code may fail, because UI thread is accessed from background thread.

If the application works as a service/batch/imersonated context (such as web app, for example), the pop-up will be shown in a separate session, not on main screen, thus no one will be able to press confirmation button.

Therefore, you SHALL NOT install certificates in `CurrentUser.Root` outside of currently interactively logged user context and be sure there is anyone who can press confirmation buttons. And avoid this code execution from bckground tasks.

Comment: it is unfortunate that my user is using Windows 10 home edition, so he cannot edit the GPO directly, I wonder if there's a reg key that can help me identify his setting?

Comment: There certainly is a reg key. But I don't know which one.

Comment: well, I found the correct reg key by using process monitor, I will try to fix this problem, thanks

Comment: @Dylech30th how did you fix this certificate issue on windows home machine ?

Comment: @humbleCodes Use the process monitor to locate the reg key, there are plenty of tutorials you can find on google, sadly since it's been too long I forgot which registry key it is, so you have to find it yourself.